# Firefox and Chromium fail to reach websites under 18.04

Tags: firefox, chromium, websites

Just installed 18.04. Firefox and Chromium fail to reach some websites, but not all. Android has no difficulty with the same sites.

Comment: Does they give any weird or different error

Comment: No, it is the usual website not found apology page.

Comment: Are you only seeing HTTPS pages or are you seeing HTTP pages too?
For security reason HTTP pages are blocked, when upgrading the security level!

Comment: Of those that I can see, both http and https sites are accessible.

Comment: Your question about security may well be relevant. I will try with and without a vpn operating. I see on other threads that the vpn in Opera produces similar failures.